# Single instance of a C# library across different processes

Tags: c#, .net, excel, dll, com-interop

I have created a C# .Net WinForms project which uses few libraries which are also created by me. Now I am creating a COM wrapper and want to use the same libraries from an Excel file through VBA. But I do not want the Excel to create a new instance of the libraries. I need to use the same instance of the libraries which are loaded by the WinForms project. Please suggest a way.

```
WinForm App 
|- Library1.dll
|- Library2.dll 
. 
Excel
|-ComWrapper
|-Library1.dll 
|-Library2.dll
```

I have tried to explain the current situation diagrammatically. In the above case two instances of Library1.dll and library2.dll will be created as they are called from different processes. I need to have just one instance of library1.dll and library2.dll in the memory.

Comment: You are not going to prevent different processes from talking to your Com enabled library.  You can prevent your own application from doing that obviously, of course it wouldn't happen, without a single line of code its hard to say what your actually asking.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish. Share some state between the two? In my book of terms "instance of library" doesn't have an entry. Describing what you are trying to accomplish will help other in the same boat as I

Comment: OK, i'll explain the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

The only easily available way to achieve this is to register your COM wrapper as a COM+ object and configure it as a "Server application" in the "Activation" tab.
You then need to use that COM+ object in both your winforms app and the Excel file.

Comment: "easily available" and COM+ in the same sentence?

Comment: Haha, good one ;-) - with "easily available" I meant that he doesn't need to create any infrastructure of his own - I personally wouldn't use it.